# Angular 2 - ng-bootstrap - How to prevent modal closing when enter key is pressed in input field

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

For NgbModal is possible to prevent the modal from closing when the enter key is pressed on a simple input field on a form ? i.e. -

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" maxlength="250" name="name" type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: Pressing enter may be submitting your form and may be your page reloads which makes modal to close

Comment: Did you use event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: you need to add more information as to your purpose as (said above) hitting return in a form will (and should) cause a submit (if the form is valid)

Comment: @MartinOcando I am not using that but will try it out.

Comment: @72GM I have a modal which has a multi select drop down box.  This seems to be composed of an input field which when enter is pressed the modal closes.

Answer (score 3):

keypress event will help you here

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" maxlength="250" name="name" type="text" name="name" (keypress)="someFunc($event)">
```

And in your component you could add this.

```
someFunc($event){
    if($event.keyCode == 13) {
         $event.preventDefault();
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but this worked for me:

```html
<input (keydown.enter)="preventDefault()" class="form-control" id="name" maxlength="250" name="name" type="text" name="name" >
```

```js
preventDefault(){
  return false;
}
```

I hope it can help to someone.